# If $x^2 +xy =10$ then when $x=2$ what is $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $x^2 +xy =10$ then when $x=2$ what is $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$?

I solved for $y=3$ before I did the product rule and i'm not sure if that was the correct way to approach it.

Comment: do you mean "when $x=2$"?

Comment: yes that is what I meant

Answer (score 2):

If $x^2+xy=10$, then $y=\frac{10}{x}-x$ (for $x\neq 0$). So $\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{10}{x^2}-1$.

This evaluated at $x=2$ is $\boxed{-\dfrac{7}{2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Use implicit differentiation

$$ x^2 + xy = 10  \iff 2x + y + xy' = 0 \iff y' = \frac{-y-2x}{x}$$

When $x = 2$, $y = 3$. hence

$$y'(2,3) = \frac{-3-2(2)}{2} = \frac{-7}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$x^2+xy=10$ then when $x=2$ what is $dy/dx$?

$$x^2+xy=10\\
4+2y=10\\
y=3$$

$$2x+x dy/dx + y=0\\
4+2 dy/dx+y=0\\
4+2 dy/dx+3=0$$

$$2 dy/dx=-7\\
dy/dx=-7/2$$

Answer (score 0):

You should use implicit differentiation here, since first solving for $y$ is meaningless (remember that the derivative is a property of functions, not of single numbers).

Thus, taking the derivative from both sides and using the product rule you get:
$$2x + y + x\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$
So that:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{2x+y}{x}$$

Comment: In this case, you can solve for $y$ in terms of $x$ first, then differentiate and evaluate the derivative for $x=2$, right?